# How can I ignore all other characters except my own created tokens in Lexer Rules?

Tags: antlr, antlr3, lexer

I have created some lexer rules to match some tokens in my input file. I want to eliminate all other characters from my input file in a single line (i.e followed by line break) other than my own tokens created earlier.

So, I have created this rule in lexer.

```
Newline : '\r'? '\n' | '\r';
...
My Own meaningful tokens
...
Others: (~Newline)* Newline;
```

But somehow this creates a confusion in the lexer about tokens that match my own meaningful tokens. Is there a tweak I can do?

Comment: There is too little information in your question. Let's say `MU` is a keyword in your language. Would the token `MUM` then be a keyword (`MU`) followed by a letter `'M'`? Or would `MUM` be one token and therefore be ignored? It's always a good idea to provide examples in your question that explain exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ok. That's interesting. But yes, I wanted to ignore all other things that are not previously captured by my `meaningful tokens`. So, yes, `MU` would be taken into considerations and M would be discarded. But I should have mentioned that I have WS(Whitespace) as a rule before my `Others` rule. So, MUM would be a wrong word there and should be reported and should not be parsed correctly by the grammar.